# R terra not reading attributes from NetCDF file

Tags: raster, r, netcdf, terra

I'm trying to read precipitation data from the Global Meteorological Forcing Dataset for land surface modeling dataset (http://hydrology.princeton.edu/data.pgf.php).

```
library(terra)
pp <- rast("~/Downloads/prec_monthly_1948-2016.nc"
```

gives

```
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 600, 1440, 828  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.0006944444, 0.001666667  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
source      : prec_monthly_1948-2016.nc 
names       : prec_~016_1, prec_~016_2, prec_~016_3, prec_~016_4, prec_~016_5, prec_~016_6, ...
```

[edited]

Is there any way of getting rast() to read the dimensions (and extent) from the NetCDF file, or must this be assigned manually?

UPDATE

I have tried reinstalling everything (R v. 4.2.1, XQuartz v. 2.8.2, RStudio v. 2022.07.0, GDAL v.3.2.2). My Mac is running MacOS Big Sur v.11.6.7.

After installing GDAL I set the path using

`export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:$PATH`

Still no joy. When I try updating terra to v.1.5-34 from source it recognizes the GDAL is present but then exits with errors

`./configure: line 3662: pkg-config: command not found`

and

`configure: error: proj_api.h not found in standard or given locations.`

I'm far outside my competence now so will revert back to raster package for now and try again when new package versions are released.

Comment: works for me, maybe upgrade terra is still pretty new - the georeferencing is handled by gdal, but you can change it with set.ext() note that works ?inplace  https://gist.github.com/mdsumner/b7fbf974dd1811186ec87c7e1e6d98d4

Comment: it must be gdal version, not terra strictly  can be different on different systems

Comment: fwiw raster uses ncdf4 which is entirely independent, so handy for flexibility - but has an unclear future

Comment: Did you create the NetCDF file you're trying to read?

Answer (score 1):

I can read this with various versions of terra, including with older versions of R and GDAL on windows and linux. It also works for me on OSX with terra 1.5.34 and gdal() returning 3.2.2.

```
library(terra)
(r <- rast("prec_monthly_1948-2016.nc"))
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 600, 1440, 828  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
#extent      : 0, 360, -60, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#source      : prec_monthly_1948-2016.nc 
#varname     : data (The data) 
#names       : data_1, data_2, data_3, data_4, data_5, data_6, ... 
#time        : 1948-01-03 to 2016-12-03 UTC
```

And to get the standard longitude extent (-180 to 180)

```
(x <- rotate(r))
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 600, 1440, 828  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -60, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#source      : memory 
#names       :    data_1,    data_2,    data_3,    data_4,    data_5,    data_6, ... 
#min values  :         0,         0,         0,         0,         0,         0, ... 
#max values  :  797.0862,  723.6213,  915.4195, 1284.7316, 1975.4684, 1486.1422, ... 
#time        : 1948-01-03 to 2016-12-03 UTC
```

Can you provide a `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: I'm on Mac, sessionInfo() is:
`R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Big Sur 11.6.7

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] terra_1.5-21 rgdal_1.5-30 sp_1.5-0    
`
...

Comment: I've tried reinstalling GDAL framework from www.kyngchaos.com but no joy.
I've tried updating terra to version 1.5-34 from source but get
`checking for gdal-config... no
no
configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘terra’`

Comment: For the sessionInfo, it is better to edit your question instead. Either way, it also works for me on OSX, so is appears to be something peculiar with your install. Perhaps the next CRAN release will fix this.

Comment: OK, thanks for confirming. I may try a complete reinstall of everything.

Comment: Package sf seems to link fine with GDAL etc.
`Linking to GEOS 3.10.2, GDAL 3.4.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE`